# Python: Multi dimensional list as the value to a key in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d1 = {}   
d2 = {}   
l1 = [1, 2, 3]   
l2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

Choice A: Initializing first key of dictionary to an empty list

```
d1[0] = []   
d1[0].append(l1)   
d1[0].append(l2)   
print(d1)   
{0: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]}
```

Choice B: Without initializing first key of dictionary to an empty list

```
d2[0] = l1    
d2[0].append(l2)     
print (d2)    
{0: [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]}
```

I am learning Python.  Could someone please explain why I see different behaviors between A and B.  I want to code the behavior in A, but do not understand why B gives a different result.  Thank you.

Comment: Quite simple really. You're appending lists to a empty list in your first example. In the second you don't start off with a empty list - you start off with `l1` that you later append `l2` to it.

Comment: Ah!, I see it now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
d2[0] = [l1]   # this needs to be a list containing l1    
d2[0].append(l2)     
print (d2)
```

Comment: Thanks, I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

this is because,

Case1:

```
d1[0] = [] # you assign a empty list to your 0 key of dict d1
d1[0].append(l1) #you append a list to the empty list {0: [[1, 2, 3]]}
d1[0].append(l2) #you append a list to the existing list
print(d1)   
{0: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]}
```

Case2:

```
d2[0]=l1 # you assign a list to your 0 key of dict d2
d2[0].append(l2) # now you append l2 list to list l1. That is l2 is added as the last element of l1
print (d2) 
{0: [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]}
```

Case3:

```
d3={}
d3[0] = [l1] # you assign a list with element l1 in it to your 0 key of dict d2 and 
d3[0].append(l2) # now you append l2 list to list that already contains l1. That is l1 is the first element and l2 is the second element
print (d3)
```

Comment: Thanks, I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

In **Choice A**:
you have assigned an empty list `[]` to `d1[0]` and later appending `l1` and `l2` as two new elements to the list `[]`.

In **Choice B**:
you have assigned `l1` itself to `d2[0]` and only appending `l2` as one new element to `l1`.

you have to remember assigning `[]` to a variable will create new list object in memory.